# Using Dictionary.app’s thesaurus function programmatically on OSX (preferably via Ruby)

Tags: ruby, macos, scripting, dictionary

I need to write a Ruby method that takes a word, runs it through OS 10.5’s Dictionary.app’s thesaurus function, and returns alternative words.

If the Ruby method ends up calling the command-line, that’s fine; I just need to be able to do it programmatically from Ruby.

After looking through Ruby OSA, I realize that the Dictionary is accessible through some Dictionary Service [http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1561332], but I don’t really get it.

Anyone see a simple solution?

I was also up for making an Automator workflow and calling it from the command line, but I wasn’t able to properly feed the "Get Definition" function a word from the shell for some reason (it kept saying that it couldn’t find the word, but when looking manually it worked).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately the only programmatic interface to this (Dictionary Services) doesn't support setting a dictionary.

However, it does consult the dictionary preferences to use the first dictionary specified, so you could potentially, in very ugly fashion, reset the preferences so the thesaurus is the only dictionary available.

This is really disgusting and likely to break if breathed upon, but it should work:

```
/* compile with:

   gcc -o thesaurus -framework CoreServices -framework Foundation thesaurus.m
*/

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryPrefs =
    [[userDefaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.DictionaryServices"] mutableCopy];

  NSArray *activeDictionaries = [dictionaryPrefs objectForKey:@"DCSActiveDictionaries"];

  [dictionaryPrefs setObject:
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"/Library/Dictionaries/Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus.dictionary"]
                      forKey:@"DCSActiveDictionaries"];
  [userDefaults setPersistentDomain:dictionaryPrefs forName:@"com.apple.DictionaryServices"];

  NSString *word = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
  puts([(NSString *)DCSCopyTextDefinition(NULL, (CFStringRef)word,
                                          CFRangeMake(0, [word length])) UTF8String]);

  [dictionaryPrefs setObject:activeDictionaries forKey: @"DCSActiveDictionaries"];
  [userDefaults setPersistentDomain:dictionaryPrefs forName:@"com.apple.DictionaryServices"];
}
```

And use it as:

```
% ./thesaurus string
noun 
1 twine, cord, yarn, thread, strand.
2 chain, group, firm, company.
3 series, succession, chain, sequence, run, streak.
4 line, train, procession, queue, file, column, convoy, cavalcade.
[...]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for posting this-- I've just compiled and tried using it on Mountain Lion, and it returns the dictionary rather than thesaurus entry.  Any idea how to adapt it for Mountain Lion?  Or perhaps a cleaner solution is now possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like the Dictionary Services API has changed since 10.5, unfortunately (file a bug!) but `DCSActiveDictionaries` moved into `NSGlobalDomain` under the `com.apple.DictionaryServices` key in 10.7.

Comment: I compiled but the resulting binary always just prints `(null)`.  I have xcodebuild -version Xcode 4.4.1 Build version 4F1003
and gcc version 4.2.1

Comment: Please read my comment — you can't use my code as is in 10.7 or 10.8, you need to modify it as I described.  (No, I am not going to write the code for you.)

Comment: Mattt Thompson has written a NSHipster article that covers this subject in a lot more detail: http://nshipster.com/dictionary-services/

Answer (score 7):

I've updated the code to work for 10.7 & 10.8. All credit to Nicholas Riley; I wouldn't have been able to write it without him!

I've modified it slightly to allow you to choose the Dictionary for the lookup, use it like: 
`$dictionary $PATH_TO_DICT $word`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

NSUserDefaults* GetUserDefaults() {
  return [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}

NSMutableDictionary* GetGlobalDomain() {
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = GetUserDefaults();
  NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryPrefs =
    [[userDefaults persistentDomainForName:@"Apple Global Domain"] mutableCopy];
  return dictionaryPrefs;
}

NSMutableDictionary* GetDictionaryPreferences() {
   return [[GetGlobalDomain() objectForKey:@"com.apple.DictionaryServices"] mutableCopy];
}

NSArray* GetCurrentDictionaryList() {
  return [GetDictionaryPreferences() objectForKey:@"DCSActiveDictionaries"];
}

void SetUserDictPreferences(NSArray* array) {
  NSMutableDictionary *currentPref = GetDictionaryPreferences();
  [currentPref setObject:array forKey:@"DCSActiveDictionaries"];
  NSDictionary *immutPref = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:currentPref];
  NSMutableDictionary *g = GetGlobalDomain();
  [g setObject:immutPref forKey:@"com.apple.DictionaryServices"];
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = GetUserDefaults();
  [defaults setPersistentDomain:g forName:@"Apple Global Domain"];
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSArray *currentPrefs = GetCurrentDictionaryList();

  NSString *dict = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
  NSString *word = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[2]];
  SetUserDictPreferences([NSArray arrayWithObject:dict]);
  puts([(NSString *)DCSCopyTextDefinition(NULL, (CFStringRef)word,
                                          CFRangeMake(0, [word length])) UTF8String]);

  SetUserDictPreferences(currentPrefs);
}
```